# Is there a gnu-as variant for targetting 64-bit code from a 32-bit system?

Tags: cross-compilation

I need to cross compile from a 32-bit system for a 64-bit target with
gnu as, but the script doing the compilation produces the error message that `x86_64-linux-as` cannot be found.

Is there a 32-bit Debian or Ubuntu package that contains `x86_64-linux-as`? I am not quite sure why the script requires `x86_64-linux-as`.  Shouldn't be possible to use the 32-bit version to produce 64-bit code?

Comment: I think you will have to build the cross tools yourself. There are many prebuilt cross toolchains at http://emdebian.org/tools/debian/ but x86_64 as a target does not seem to be among them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu`](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu), available in Debian Jessie (but not Ubuntu). It contains `x86_64-linux-gnu-as`, so you need to configure using `x86_64-linux-gnu` as target.